# How to upload file to Laravel server from Android device using Retrofit correctly

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload an image from Android Studio to Laravel server using Retrofit2 Multipart encoding, but i keep getting "500 Internal Server Error", which means something is going wrong server-side probably, but i can't pin what it is.

this is my interface call (Android Studio):

```
@Multipart
@POST("public/imagem")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImagem(@Part MultipartBody.Part part,
                                @Part("name") RequestBody name,
                                @Part("animal_id") long animal_id,
                                @Part("ativo") int ativo);
```

this is the request (Android Studio):

```
    //Create a file object using file path
    File file = new File(filePath);
    // Create a request body with file and image media type
    RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
    // Create MultipartBody.Part using file request-body,file name and part name
    MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload", file.getName(), fileReqBody);
    //Create request body with text description and text media type
    RequestBody name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "image-type");

    WebService.getInstance().getService().uploadImagem(part, name, animal_id, 1).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO GET
            } else {
                //THIS IS WHERE IM GETTING AT EVERYTIME
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

this is my route (Laravel):

```
Route::post('imagem','ImagemController@createImagem');
```

this is the "createImagem" function inside "ImagemController" (Laravel):

```
public function createImagem(Request $request){

$destinationPath = url('/midia'); //i have a "midia" folder inside "public" folder
$image = $request->file('part');
$name = $request->input('name');
$image->move($destinationPath, $name);

$dbPath = $destinationPath. '/'.$name;
$imagem = new Imagem();
$imagem->animal_id = $request->input('animal_id');
$imagem->img_url = $dbPath;
$imagem->ativo = $request->input('ativo');   
$imagem->save();

return response()->json($imagem);
}
```

and these are the attributes inside "Imagem" table and their types:
[image]

but i'm getting 500 Internal Server Error, so probably something server-side isn't according to what would be right logically, can you help me find what is wrong in my code?

ps. I do have other requests to this server that are fully functional, but all of them are just fields, while this has a file, which needs Multipart encoding, unlike the others.

EDIT:
This is the server error log:

```
[2019-06-11 21:21:03] local.ERROR: Call to a member function move() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function move() on null at /.../Controllers/ImagemController.php:28)
```

So it seems i am unable to get file with

```
$image = $request->file('part');
```

Comment: check server error log

Comment: Hi bro i am backend developer why you dont use storage for upload image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error could be because path must to be a path and not an url:

```
$destinationPath = url('/midia');
```

If you want to move the file to public folder, you have to use `public_path()` for the path:

```
$image = $request->file('part');
$destinationPath = 'midia';
$name = $request->input('name') .'.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$image->move(public_path($destinationPath), $name);
```

If you want to avoid the error and not waste server resources when there is no image in the request, add a validation at the start of your function:

```
public function createImagem(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'part' => 'required|image|max:2048',
        // other fields validations
    ]);
    // the createImagem logic here
}
```

if the validation fails, you will not try to move the file and will not query DB either, then the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the client where you can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

try this code hope its helpfull for you.

```
 @Multipart
@POST("public/imagem")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImagem(@Part MultipartBody.Part part);
```

if you are using key part 
`$image = $request->file('part');`

also use that key "part" in java code

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(event_image);
        File file = new File(uri1.getPath());
        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

        MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("part", file.getName(), reqFile);



        mService.addEvent(image).enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```